# How to acces my variable outside of my class?

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm just starting to learn how to code, and I'm facing an issue. This is the first time I'm dealing with classes, and I have a simple program to make, but even though it is simple I'm have trouble making it work.

It is not finished, nor cleaned up so It'll look messy, but I need someone's help to move ahead.
In my code, I'm try to run a loop to creates instances of an object, and the number of instances is defined by the user in my Sousfenetre() class.
Inside that class, I have methods, including one which sets the variable 'nbrboules'
I'm trying to access its values at the end of my code, but can't seem to figure out how to.

(And if someone could explain why "nbr" Stringvar() isn't showing in "saisie" Entry widget, and why self.nbr.get() returns the wrong value, that would be nice as well :)

```
from tkinter import *
import random

fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.title("Boules")
fenetre.geometry("600x600")
Tx,Ty = 600,600
canvas = Canvas(fenetre,height=600,width=600,bg="yellow")
canvas.pack()

class Sousfenetre(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        global label
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.nbr = StringVar()
        self.nbr.set("Entrez un nombre entier")

        self.saisie = Entry(self, textvariable=self.nbr, width=200)
        self.saisie.grid(row=0)

        self.bouton = Button(self, text="VALIDER", font=(None, 30), command=self.valider)
        self.bouton.grid(row=1)

        self.label = Label(self, text="")
        self.label.grid(row=2)

    def valider(self):
        global nbrboules,label
        try:
            nbrboules = int(self.saisie.get())
            # POURQUOI SELF.NBR.GET() RENVOIE LA MAUVAISE VALEUR PUTAIN
            self.destroy()
        except ValueError:
            self.label.config(text="Entrez un nombre entier !")

    def access(self):
        return self.nbrboules




class Boule():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=random.randint(10,590)
        self.y = random.randint(10, 590)
        self.dx = random.randint(20,40)
        self.dy = random.randint(20, 40)
        self.r = random.randint(2,10)

    def inversedx(self):
        self.dx = -self.dx

    def inversedy(self):
        self.dy = -self.dy

    def deplacementx(self):
        self.x += self.dx

    def deplacementy(self):
        self.y += self.y

    def setdx(self,param):
        self.x = param

    def setdy(self,param):
        self.y = param

    def collisionBords(self,Tx,Ty):
        if self.x + self.dx > Tx - self.r or self.x + self.dx < 0 + self.r :
            return self.x
        if self.y + self.dy > Ty - self.r or self.y + self.dy < 0 + self.r :
            return self.y

#    def collisionBoule(self,boule):
#        if abs(self.x - boule.x) and abs(self.y - boule.y) < self.r + boule.r:
Sousfenetre()
listeboule = []
Cercles = []
couleur = ["blue","red","green"]
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
listeboule.append(Boule())
#I know this isn't efficient, it was for testing purposes
f = Sousfenetre()
for i in range(0,f.access()):
    Cercles.append(canvas.create_oval(listeboule[i].x-listeboule[i].r,listeboule[i].y-listeboule[i].r,listeboule[i].x+listeboule[i].r,listeboule[i].y+listeboule[i].r,fill=random.choice(couleur)))

print(listeboule)
def test():
    print(nbrboules)


fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't know what means `Sousfenetre` but it seems main window - and you should create it only once and assign to varialbe `f = Sousfenetre()` and then you should have access to its elements `f.nbrboules`

Comment: BTW: tkinter should have only one main window - create with `Tk()`. To create other windows use `Toplevel()`

Comment: for Python `nbrboules` and `self.nbrboules` are two different variables - better use one of them.

Comment: to make code more readable it is good to keep all classes and functions before `fenetre = Tk()`

Comment: your code gives me error message. always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `mainloop()` starts program - it shows windows. If you want to add items to `Cercles` using values from `f.access()` then do it inside `valider` which is executed when you click button. if you will try to do it before `mainloop()` then Python will try to do it before you see window (and before you click button).

Comment: if I use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk` in `class Sousfenetre(Toplevel):` then `Entry` shows text from `self.nbr`

Comment: Hello @furas thank you for answering my question. I will try to clarify myself. I know the `Toplevel()` method is the way to go, but I really wanted to train myself in creating classes. `Sousfenetre()` actually is a secondary window which is only here for integer selection, and should be destroyed once an integer has been chosen, to choose how many items to create in `Cercles`. I've tried assigning `f = Sousfenetre()` and accessing `f.nbrboules` but I get this error : `AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'nbrboules'` Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: problem is that you try to do it before `mainloop()` which shows `Sousfenetre` on screen - so you try to get value before you put it in `Entry`. All GUI frameworks work different then console programs - `mainloop` starts program and everythink before `mainloop` is only information for `mainlooop` what to display in windows. If you have to do it something then do it in function assigned to button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me.

It uses `Toplevel` to creates `Sousfenetre` so `Entry` displays text from `self.nbr`.

Because `mainloop` starts program so everything before `mainloop` is executed before you press button. I sends `listeboule`, `cercles` to `Sousfenetre` as parameters and it can use them in `valider` when you press button.

I also used `fenetre.after(100, f.lift)` to move `Sousfenetre` to the front 100ms after creating main window so it is not hidden behind main window.

---

```
import tkinter as tk # `import *` is not preferred 
import random

# --- classes ---

class Sousfenetre(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, listeboule, cercles):
        super().__init__() # in Python 3 you can use `super()` instead of class name

        # remeber as class variable to have access in other methods
        self.listeboule = listeboule
        self.cercles = cercles

        self.nbr = tk.StringVar()
        self.nbr.set("Entrez un nombre entier")

        self.saisie = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.nbr)
        self.saisie.grid(row=0)

        self.bouton = tk.Button(self, text="VALIDER", command=self.valider)
        self.bouton.grid(row=1)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.label.grid(row=2)

    def valider(self):
        try:
            nbrboules = int(self.saisie.get())

            # uses
            for i in range(nbrboules):
                b = self.listeboule[i]
                c = random.choice(couleur)
                self.cercles.append(canvas.create_oval(b.x-b.r, b.y-b.r, b.x+b.r, b.y+b.r, fill=c))

            self.destroy()
        except ValueError:
            self.label.config(text="Entrez un nombre entier !")


class Boule():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(10,590)
        self.y = random.randint(10, 590)
        self.dx = random.randint(20,40)
        self.dy = random.randint(20, 40)
        self.r = random.randint(2,10)

    def inversedx(self):
        self.dx = -self.dx

    def inversedy(self):
        self.dy = -self.dy

    def deplacementx(self):
        self.x += self.dx

    def deplacementy(self):
        self.y += self.y

    def setdx(self,param):
        self.x = param

    def setdy(self,param):
        self.y = param

    def collisionBords(self,Tx,Ty):
        if self.x + self.dx > Tx - self.r or self.x + self.dx < 0 + self.r :
            return self.x
        if self.y + self.dy > Ty - self.r or self.y + self.dy < 0 + self.r :
            return self.y

# --- functions ---

# empty

# --- main ---

#listeboule = []
#for _ in range(12):
#    listeboule.append(Boule())

listeboule = [Boule() for _ in range(12)] # create 12 circles
cercles = []
couleur = ["blue", "red", "green"]

Tx = 600
Ty = 600

# ---

fenetre = tk.Tk()
fenetre.title("Boules")
fenetre.geometry("600x600")

canvas = tk.Canvas(fenetre, height=600, width=600, bg="yellow")
canvas.pack()

# send `listeboule`, `cercles` to class 
f = Sousfenetre(listeboule, cercles)

# Move `Sousfenetre` to the front 100ms after creating main window.
# This way Sousfenetre is not hidden behind main window.
fenetre.after(100, f.lift)

# start program
fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I get it now ! and the addition of `f.lift` is exactly what I needed ! Thanks for your time and knowledge :) !